# dovecot-core purge/reinstall error

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dpkg, dovecot

Recently dovecot was shown to need updating. No problem...

Except that it barks this error out: /usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected

and collapses on itself. So I think for a while.. maybe it's an old conflict, we've upgraded a few times. I run iredmail, lets backup our configurations and flush it, rebuild it, and I'll just diff out the changes.

I can't remove the file:

```
Purging configuration files for dovecot-core (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.1) ...
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 56: [: : integer expression expected
ucfr: Association belongs to , not dovecot-core
ucfr: Aborting
dpkg: error processing package dovecot-core (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 5
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing..
```

So I go into the /var/lib/dpkg/info directory and read up on its removal. I remove further nooks and crannies of what I can find. I believe at this time I have everything. I turn back to reinstall just the core, and we have:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dovecot-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,420 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,578 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package dovecot-core.
(Reading database ... 177431 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dovecot-core_1%3a2.2.22-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dovecot-core (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up dovecot-core (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.1) ...
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected

Creating config file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf with new version
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 56: [: : integer expression expected
ucfr: Association belongs to , not dovecot-core
ucfr: Aborting
dpkg: error processing package dovecot-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 5
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dovecot-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've searched high and low and can't find a reference for how to handle this. I'm pretty lost and now I have an utterly broken dovecot.

Thoughts anyone before I figure out my last backup and rollback?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in `/usr/bin/ucfr`. As a workaround you could remove the `ucfr` call from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/dovecot-core.postrm`:

In line 19 change

```
ucfr --purge dovecot-core $conffile
```

to

```
true ucfr --purge dovecot-core $conffile
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get purge dovecot-core
```

If that works reinstall `dovecot-core`

Comment: Thanks Florian. That allows for a full purge of dovecot-core but on the (re)install the second set of code (pasted) blows back up again.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /var/lib/ucf/registry` and `egrep --count "[[:space:]]/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf" /var/lib/ucf/registry`

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50 Oct  4 17:22 /var/lib/ucf/registry and nothing comes up for the second command.

Comment: What's  the output of the second command?

Comment: There was nothing. Linefeed.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your `egrep`, it should print a number.  What's the output of  `which egrep`  and `echo | egrep --count a`?

Comment: Both of those lead to/print nothing. Looking in egrep it's just a shell to grep: #!/bin/sh
exec grep -E "$@" -- I forced a reinstall of grep (which says it contains the egrep/fgrep facilities and this changed nothing.)

Comment: I've done a rollback and a hold on the dovecot tree for now. If you have any further thoughts I'm open to them for re-testing.