# /usr/bin/ucfr Errors integer expression expected

Tags: 16.04, error-handling

Sometime in the last year I've had an error creep into my installs and I don't have the where-with-all to track it down.

The first time I saw it rear its head was in:

[dovecot-core update error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833113/dovecot-core-purge-reinstall-error)

Which never saw a solution that worked, so I froze out the updates.

I've seen it bobble into view during some updates but it's never stopped me again until now.

[grub-pc update failing](https://serverfault.com/questions/827873/grub-pc-update-fail-dev-sda-ext2-doesnt-support-embedding)

Since I first try to solve what looks like an error; which usually entails removing/reinstalling--I've basically broken grub to a point where I am uncertain I will boot because the package never fully installs.

All due to whatever ucfr is having a problem with (example):

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.6) ...
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 110: [: : integer expression expected
```

or

```
Purging configuration files for dovecot-core (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.1) ...
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 323: [: : integer expression expected
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 56: [: : integer expression expected
```

Whatever the /usr/bin/ucfr issue is it manifests roughly the same way over many packages. I just don't know how to unpack the problem and find a way to resolve the core issue.

Thoughts and considerations deeply appreciated.

Running:

- Linux 4.8.6-x86_64-linode78 [..] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
- GNU/Linux Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Release: 16.04 Codename: xenial

Comment: Can you please add the output of `ls -l /var/lib/ucf/registry`?

Comment: @steeldriver `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28 Jan 23 15:58 /var/lib/ucf/registry`

Comment: Hmm ... well there goes that idea (I'm trying to figure out why the `grep` by which `$count` is assigned would fail)

Comment: Is that something that's being called in a script that's erroring @steeldriver?

Comment: /usr/bin/ucfr is itself a script - it greps the registry file to count entries - the only way I could think it might fail (rather than return a count of 0) is if the registry file did not exist or was not readable. Maybe it's malformed? If it's not too long, maybe you could post its contents (it's just a text file AFAIK) i.e. `cat /var/lib/ucf/registry`. Also interesting might be `diff /var/lib/ucf/registry{,.0}`

Comment: Sure @steeldriver: `grub-pc   /etc/default/grub` is the contents, the diff returned noithing.